How to handle MQ messages if listener Job ended abnormally
we have a RPGLE listener application that receives message request from local queue coming from
External system. Sequence flow are:

MQConn
MQOpen
Loop to Get all messages using MQGet until it receives ‘*EOM’ request
MQClose

May I get your insights on how handle the scenario if the listener job is manually ended with immediate end option? The result is that all messages retrieved and processed during MQGet are all loaded back to local queue.
How to permanently commit those messages that are already fetched. Thank you in advance.
Ramon

Add a MQCMIT call into your loop after each successful processing of a message.
Invoke MQBACK instead if MQGET was successful but subsequent processing of the message was not. This rolls back the transaction (MQ only) and this particular message goes back to the queue.
